# Whisper into or whisper in?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrases, prepositions, collocation

Which is the correct one:

> 1. She whispered in his ear.

Or

> 2. She whispered into his ear.

Comment: I can't see there's much difference in the way they're used, which is surprising, because 'into' would seem the logical choice.

Comment: Either is correct. Which sounds better to you?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - But it's not really surprising, considering one meaning of _in_ is [_into_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in#Preposition).

Comment: @JR They're often used differently. 'He ran into the room' and 'he ran in the room' / 'She looked into the room' and 'she looked in the room'... And where the 'into' sense is intended, the 'in' alternative is by no means always available: We went into town / what's he got into now? /  she flounced into the meeting....

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whispered+in+his+ear%2Cwhispered+into+his+ear&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhispered%20in%20his%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhispered%20into%20his%20ear%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

*[Let me whisper in your ear](http://www.thebeatles.com/song/do-you-want-know-secret)*, said the Beatles. And [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whisper%20in%20*%20ear%2C%20whisper%20into%20*%20ear&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cwhisper%20in%20%2A%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20his%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20her%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20my%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20your%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20the%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20their%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20our%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20thine%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20its%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20in%20mine%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cwhisper%20into%20%2A%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwhisper%20into%20the%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20into%20his%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20into%20your%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20into%20her%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20into%20my%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20into%20their%20ear%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhisper%20into%20its%20ear%3B%2Cc0) shows that ***in*** is much preferred over ***into***:

[image]

Comment: Granted that Ngram is often the go-to reference here, I don't always see how popularity proves what's preferred except in identical situations. I am open to learning whether to use in or into, but Ngram does not show a comparison that is apples to apples. For example, if red apples showed up more than green do, the frequency makes no comment on green good or bad. If, however, red apples showed up more than redd do, I could suspect a misspelling. Meaning no disrespect to using the utility.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I fully agree with your reservations in general. However, I don't think they apply in this case. I cannot imagine a scenario where any one of the charted phrases could be used in a situation that is not "identical" in the sense you have used it. Be it as it may, it is only a tool and anyone can (and should) interpret the results for themselves. To me, the first reference is far more than enough and the Ngram is just a corroboration.

Comment: The perhaps more likely 'whispered in/into his ear' also show this pattern, with a fairly constant ratio around 3 : 1. OP should have researched this, but +1 for the effort and new-to-me type of colour coding.

Answer (score 0):

I like how this writer made the distinction between the two words:

"The word 'in' is used to denote a state when something is enclosed by something else. 'into' is used to express motion wherein something comes inside from outside and then it is enclosed."

Found here: https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-in-and-into.html

See the article for examples.

Comment: But I'd say 'whispered in his ear' connotes a farcical 'Honey I shrunk the kids' scenario.